# Hindi english code mix language translation to english or hindi

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, google-translation-api

i want to transliterate hindi english code mix language (popularly known as hinglish) to english .I tried google transliterate api ,but its not showing correct results is there any other alternative to that .for eg :- kya haal hai? to how are you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using?